# Regarding the (possible)effects of magnetic field on dielectric polarization and the electric fields on magnetization

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

The dielectric Polarization vector $\vec P$ is related to the macroscopic electric field by the constitutive relation [image]

((source : wikipedia))

Which hints that the Polarization depends only on the Electric field , my question is **does it also depend on the magnetic field** because the magnetic field can influence(by exerting a force) the polarization current $\frac{d\vec P}{dt}$ and hence $\vec P$ .If it is so why is the magnetic field not accounted for in the above constitutive relation?

Also , I wonder if the electric field could somehow inlfluence the magnetization vector $\vec M$ somehow,but lack clarity in thought.
Also my current educational background is i'm a 2nd year undergraduate studying classical electrodynamics for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of a magnetic field on electric polarization or vice versa, the effect of an electric field on magnetization are two phenomena theoretically possible and observed in experiments.  However, the cross-influence of electric and magnetic fields on magnetic and electric polarization is usually a significantly weak effect, which explains why it is usually not discussed in introductions to electromagnetism in materials.

Still, the effect exists and it is possible to find more details in this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoelectric_effect).